# How do I fix the MalformedURLException here?

Tags: java

I want the program to print out the text of each url

```
HtmlPage points = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://www.hockey-reference.com/leaders/points_career.html");
String pointsPageContent=points.asText();

HtmlPage assists = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://www.hockey-reference.com/leaders/assists_career.html");
String assistsPageContent=assists.asText();




final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(pointsPageContent);

final HtmlPage page2 = webClient.getPage(assistsPageContent);




if(input == "Points") {
    System.out.println(page1);

}

else if(input == "Assists") {
System.out.println(page2);
}

else {
    System.out.println("not a valid entry, please type either 'Points' or 'Assists' to see the stats for the corresponding category");
}
```

I'm supposed to get the text for each URL, but it's giving me the MalformedURLException instead.

Comment: Please put the name of the library you are using in the tags or in the question. Also, regardless of your Exception, you should not compare strings with `==`.

Comment: You appear to be fetching the page once, then fetching the *contents* of the page (i.e. the HTML) as if it were a URL. You've already fetched both pages after the first few lines of code - what do you expect `page1` and `page2` to be?

Comment: Stack trace of the Exception? Also, pointsPageContent and assistsPageContent are not urls.

Comment: As far as I can see the 2 URLs you have provided are both valid so neither should be throwing that exception. As others have mentioned you need to give some more details: The stacktrace, and line that is causing the issue would be a good start, the library being used would also help (my guess would be you are using HtmlUnit).

Comment: Yes I'm using HtmlUnit and it says that the issue is with the line that has page1.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Maybe HtmlUnit, but not sure about it.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: NHL & WHA Career Leaders and Records for Points | Hockey-Reference.com               
 at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
 at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.UrlUtils.toUrlUnsafe(UrlUtils.java:243)
 at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:448)
 at SpringProject.main(SpringProject.java:56)

Comment: As @JonSkeet said, this error occur because you're fetch the contents of the page as if it were a URL.

Comment: @FilipeManuel how do I fix it so it's not fetching it like a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JonSkeet said, this error occur because you're fetch the contents of the page as if it were a URL.

```
    try {
        HtmlPage points = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://www.hockey-reference.com/leaders/points_career.html");
        String pointsPageContent = points.asText();

        HtmlPage assists = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://www.hockey-reference.com/leaders/assists_career.html");
        String assistsPageContent = assists.asText();

        if (input.equals("Points")) {
            System.out.println(pointsPageContent);

        } else if (input.equals("Assists")) {
            System.out.println(assistsPageContent);
        } else {
            System.out.println("not a valid entry, please type either 'Points' or 'Assists' to see the stats for the corresponding category");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); // Capture and treat errors
    }
```

Just compare page content with desired input.